# Show that $(T_{ij})=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha &\omega &0\\-\omega & \alpha &0\\ 0 &0& \beta \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, tensors

> A tensor has components $T_{ij}$ with respect to Cartesian coordinates
>    $x$. If the tensor is invariant under arbitrary rotations around the
>    $x_3$-axis, show that it must have the form $$(T_{ij})=\begin{pmatrix}
>  \alpha &\omega &0\\-\omega & \alpha &0\\ 0 &0& \beta \end{pmatrix}$$

Surely we want $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta &\sin\theta &0\\-\sin\theta & \cos\theta&0\\ 0 &0& 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} T_{11} &T_{12} &T_{13}\\T_{21}& T_{22}&T_{23}\\ T_{31}&T_{32}&T_{33}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} T_{11} &T_{12} &T_{13}\\T_{21}& T_{22}&T_{23}\\ T_{31}&T_{32}&T_{33}\end{pmatrix}$ but we then have $(\cos\theta )T_{11}+(\sin\theta) T_{21}=T_{11}$ and $(\cos\theta) T_{21}-(\sin\theta) T_{11}=T_{21}$ which eventually leads to $1-\cos\theta=\cos\theta-1$ which must hold for all $\theta$ which is clearly wrong, unless $T_{11}/T_{21}=0$ which again is wrong.

What am I doing wrong? Is my approach fundamentally wrong? I imagine I am underestimating the question quite a but (if this method were to work that would make the question far easier than expected), I suspect there's a lot more to the question I'm not considering or my approach is wrong altogether.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I have not examine this in detail, but is there a reason wh you are only looking at the entries in the first column? Why don't you write out the entire operation on Mathematica or something? Surely it can solve such an equation for you.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but for tensor invariant under rotations don't you mean: $T = B \, T \, B^{-1} $? Where $T= (T_{ij}) $ and $ B$ is the matrix of a rotation around the $x_3$ axis?

Comment: @Federico You're probably right, I'll try that tomorrow (later as technically it's now Tuesday) and see if it gives the required form.

Answer (score 1):

I think your calculation is right.
Let $R_\theta$ be a $2\times 2$ rotational matrix, observe that
\begin{align}
R_\theta M = M \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (I-R_\theta)M= 0
\end{align}
for all $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ implies $M = 0$.

I think you might be confusing something here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer yet again, it seems you've more or less guided me through this entire course. Clearly I must be confusing something, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Did I answer some other question of your?